# Didn't show desired output

Tags: python, sockets, raspberry-pi, port, host

Hello fellow programmer.
I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QihjI84Z2tQ 
Those server and client has successfully connected
but when i try build it did not show the desired output on the client-side terminal.
The server-side terminal does not react anything.

this is my code for server side:

```
import socket
import numpy as np
import encodings

HOST = '192.168.0.177'  # Standard loopback interface address (localhost)
PORT = 65432        # Port to listen on (non-privileged ports are > 1023)


def random_data():          # ANY DATA YOU WANT TO SEND WRITE YOUR SENSOR CODE HERE

    x1 = np.random.randint(0, 55, None)         # Dummy temperature
    y1 = np.random.randint(0, 45, None)         # Dummy humidigy
    my_sensor = "{},{}".format(x1,y1)
    return my_sensor                            # return data seperated by comma


def my_server():

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        print("Server Started waiting for client to connect ")
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
        s.listen(5)
        conn, addr = s.accept()

        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            while True:

                data = conn.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

                if str(data) == "Data":

                    print("Ok Sending data ")

                    my_data = random_data()

                    x_encoded_data = my_data.encode('utf-8')

                    conn.sendall(x_encoded_data)

                elif  str(data) == "Quit":
                    print("shutting down server ")
                    break

                if not data:
                    break
                else:
                    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while 1:
        my_server()
```

and this is my client code:

```
import socket
import threading
import time


HOST = '192.168.0.177'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 65432        # The port used by the server


def process_data_from_server(x):
    x1, y1 = x.split(",")
    return x1,y1


def my_client():
    threading.Timer(11, my_client).start()

    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))

        my = input("Data")

        my_inp = my.encode('utf-8')

        s.sendall(my_inp)

        data = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')

        x_temperature,y_humidity = process_data_from_server(data)

        print("Temperature {}".format(x_temperature))
        print("Humidity {}".format(y_humidity))

        s.close()
        time.sleep(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while 1:
        my_client()
```

I have tried many solution by printing `"Data"` directly to the terminal.
can anyone help me?

Comment: Perhaps you should put a `print(data)` in that final `else:` in the server code, so that you can see what you actually are receiving, if it isn't one of your two implemented commands.

Comment: first use `print(data)` after `data = ...` to see what you get from server. Maybe you get something different then you expect.

Comment: BTW: `else: pass` is useless - you can remove it. Instead of `while 1:` you can use `while True:` beacuse it is more readable (all people use it)

Comment: BTW: socket is low-level (primitive) construction. IT can send `Data` and `temperature,humidity` so fast so client can get it as one string when you use `recv(1024)` - ie. `"Data15,95"`. You may have to use `recv(4)` to make sure you get only `"Data"` or `"Quit"`

Comment: but how about the port? can u explain that to me? how he pory work?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the problem. I am using Sublime Text 3 when running the client.py script When i post in the build it doesnt response nothing. So I change my IDE to PYCharm and then it worked. I don't know why. I hope that's helpful to other people that have this problem. Thank you very much.